# Pyspark UDF to round one column to the precision specified by another column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am trying to make a UDF in pyspark to round one column to the precision specified, in each row, by another column, e.g., the following dataframe:

```py
+--------+--------+
|    Data|Rounding|
+--------+--------+
|3.141592|       3|
|0.577215|       1|
+--------+--------+
```

when submitted to said UDF should give the following result:

```py
+--------+--------+--------------+
|    Data|Rounding|Rounded Column|
+--------+--------+--------------+
|3.141592|       3|         3.142|
|0.577215|       1|           0.6|
+--------+--------+--------------+
```

In particular, I have tried the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, FloatType, LongType, 
IntegerType

pdDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Data", "Rounding"], data=[[3.141592, 3], 
   [0.577215, 1]])

mySchema = StructType([ StructField("Data", FloatType(), True), 
StructField("Rounding", IntegerType(), True)])

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("column 
rounding").getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame(pdDF,schema=mySchema)

df.show()

def round_column(Data, Rounding):
return (lambda (Data, Rounding): round(Data, Rounding), FloatType())

spark.udf.register("column rounded to the precision specified by another", 
round_column, FloatType())


df_rounded = df.withColumn('Rounded Column', round_column(df["Data"], 
df["Rounding"]))

df_rounded .show()
```

but I get the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "whatever.py", line 21, in <module>
    df_redondeado = df.withColumn('columna_redondeada',round_column(df["Data"], df["Rounding"]))
  File "whomever\spark\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 1848, in withColumn
    assert isinstance(col, Column), "col should be Column"
AssertionError: col should be Column
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answer, your udf is not valid.

You can either use a inline udf as below:

```py
udf_round_column = udf(lambda row: round(row['data'], row['rounding']), FloatType())
df_rounded = df.withColumn('rounded_col', udf_round_column(struct('data', 'rounding')))
```

or as a separate function:

```py
def round_column(data, rounding):
    return round(data, rounding)

udf_round_column= udf(round_column, FloatType())
df_rounded = df.withColumn('rounded_col', udf_round_to_decimal('data', 'rounding'))
```

Both returns this:

```py
+---+---------+--------+-----------+
| id|     data|rounding|rounded_col|
+---+---------+--------+-----------+
|  1|3.1415926|       3|      3.142|
|  2|  0.12345|       6|    0.12345|
|  3|   2.3456|       1|        2.3|
+---+---------+--------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code fails because `round_column` is not a valid `udf`. You should

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

@udf(FloatType())
def round_column(data, rounding):
    return round(data, rounding)
```

`spark.udf.register` is used to register functions which are called from SQL queries, so it is not applicable here.

However you don't need `udf` at all. Just:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df_rounded = df.withColumn('Rounded Column', 'expr(round(Data, Rounding))')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining that a udf is used in sql queries, however, could you please clarify which expression I should use in  'expr(round(Data, Rounding))' ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to apply an UDF to a dataframe then can simply import it like

`from pyspark.sql.functions import udf`

and use it like

`round_column_udf = udf(round_column, FloatType())
df_rounded = df.withColumn('Rounded_Column', round_column_udf(df['Data'], df['Rounding']))`

Registering a udf is used with spark sql queries like

`spark.udf.register("round_column_udf",round_column, FloatType())
df.registerTempTable("df")
spark.sql("select Data, Rounding,round_column_udf(Data, Rounding) as Rounded_Column from df").show()`

both should work..